# Emacs on Windows for C++ development configuration?

Tags: emacs, windows-7, cygwin, windows-7-x64

Has anyone set up cygwin and some emacs to work well under a 64-bit Windows 7?

I tried downloading cygwin recently, and by default not even dired works reliably, there are odd shell prompt characters, I get a lot of warnings, in one case C-c was read as C-g and caused various errors. (Neither xemacs nor emacs worked for me, where by "work" I mean that dired and shell work, and without warnings).

I just want the usual emacs development tools: gdb-mode, shell-mode, compiling, tag-search to work as normal.

I was hoping someone who has done this recently with cygwin could share whatever relevant shell files, emacs files, environment variables, and so on to make this all work. Should all these things just work out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out ntemacs, with this code in your .emacs everything is working great with cygwin:

```
;; -- sets up cygwin
(let* ((cygwin-root "c:/cygwin")
  (cygwin-bin (concat cygwin-root "/bin")))
(when (and (eq 'windows-nt system-type)
  (file-readable-p cygwin-root))
(setq exec-path (cons cygwin-bin exec-path))
(setenv "PATH" (concat cygwin-bin ";" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name) 
(setq explicit-shell-file-name shell-file-name) 
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-strip-ctrl-m)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a hideous Frankenstein mix of "native" Win32 emacs (http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/windows/emacs-23.1.97-bin-i386.zip is the latest, but I'm using an older version) and Cygwin -- for bash, find, etc. It's taken me years to tweak things to my liking, and it's still a pretty bumpy experience.

Anyway it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I use a straight clean install of Emacs, gcc, gdb, make, etc from Cygwin (currently 1.7.15, but I've been doing this for years) and my standard dotfiles (.emacs, .bashrc/.bash_profile) that have been tweaked (but not really heavily) to be portable across Linux and Cygwin, and everything works fine for me. Occasionally I run into problems (like with [processing2-mode](https://github.com/ptrv/processing2-emacs) where Processing doesn't have a Cygwin package yet, so it wants native Windows paths, but that's easily enough fixed and out of the ordinary. It almost sounds to me like something is fundamentally broken on your setup; could you give more details? Otherwise all I can recommend is wipe and do a clean reinstall.